# Default Method of Built-in Persistent Storage Type Of Core Data In Xcode

Tags: core-data, swift4, swift4.2

According to apple doc's Persistent Store Types and Behaviors, the built-in persistent store types of core data are
1. XML
2. Binary
3. SQLite
4. In Memory

My Question is,
       Among these which is the default store type when we use core data model in xcode and how can we change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `NSPersistentStore` is an abstract base class.  One of its four subclasses must be deliberately created in code.  So, there is not really a *default* store type.

There is, however some template code which gets generated when you choose one of the *New Project* or *New Target* templates in Xcode.  In the current version (Xcode 10), when you switch on the *Use Core Data* checkbox, you get in the `AppDelegate` implementation a `lazy var persistentContainer` property which provides a singleton `NSPersistentContainer` object.  This is by default the store you will use in the new target.  But what store type is that?  Well, the persistent store(s) of a `NSPersistentContainer` are specified in its `persistentStoreDescriptions` array property.  By default, this array contains one persistent store of type SQLite, backed by a file in the `Application Support` folder of your app's container.  This is, in a round-about way, the *default store type* you asked about.

The procedure to change this store type is explained in the *Discussion* section of [the documentation of NSPersistentContainer.persistentstoredescriptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcontainer/1640577-persistentstoredescriptions).

So you see the *default* is actually in the Xcode Project Templates.  To get what you want, you can place the code you wrote after reading that documentation into a new Project Template and add it to your `~/Library`.  You can either override one of the default Project Templates, or create your own with a new name.  A basic example is given in this [blog post by Jake Craige](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/creating-custom-xcode-templates).  If that is not enough for you, Keith Harrison has published a quite [thorough reverse engineering of Xcode Project Templates](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/creating-custom-xcode-project-templates/).

Comment: Thanks For The Clear Explanation